# Confirm box is not render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch. The problem which I am facing, this is my first test application.

```
Ext.Msg.confirm('', 'Are you sure you want to reset this form?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn === 'yes') {
                    } 
                });
```

The problem is with confirm box styling. Its coming but its not rendering proper. 
Here is the attach screen shot
[image]

The code which I used is

BillingForm.js

```
Ext.define("test.view.BillingForm", {
  extend: "Ext.Container",
  config: {
    items: [{
        title: "Basic",
        xtype: "formpanel",
        id: "billingForm",
        items: [
          {
            xtype: "fieldset",
            title: "Billing Information",
            defaults: {
              labelWidth: "32%",
              style: {
                "background-color": "#fff",
                "font-size": "12px",
                "color": "#333"

              }
            },
            items: [
              {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'firstname',
                label: 'First Name',
                palceholder: "Enter your first name",
                required: true,
                focus: true

              }
            ]
          },
          {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Reset',
            ui: 'decline',
            handler: function(btn, evt) {
               Ext.Msg.confirm('', 'Are you sure you want to reset this form?', function (btn) {
                    if (btn === 'yes') {
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

MainView.js

```
Ext.define('test.view.MainView', {
    extend : "Ext.Container",
    alias : ["widget.mainview"],
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
            type: "vbox"
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: "toolbar",
            docked: "top",
            height: 45,
            title: "First App"
        },
         Ext.create("test.view.BillingForm",{
            height:300,
            padding:"10 0 0 0"
        })

        ],
    }
});
```

app.js

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.application({
        name: 'test',
        appFolder : 'app',
        models : [],
        stores : [],
        requires: [],
        views: ["MainView","BillingForm"],
        controllers:    [],
        isIconPrecomposed : true,
        profiles : [],
        launch: function() {
            Ext.create("test.view.BillingForm", {});
        }
    });
});
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link href="http://localhost/projects/touch/resources/css/cupertino.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://localhost/projects/touch/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has lot of issues. Here is a list of issues I can see just by casting a glance at your code:

1. When you use Ext.application function, you do not need Ext.onReady. Just remove it.
2. In the launch function, create your MainView instead of BillingForm
3. Addition of BillingForm in MainView is wrong. Provide xtype : 'billingform' in the definition of BillingForm just below extend:'Ext.Container' and then in the items of MainView, instead of creating new BillingForm, just add it like this:

   ```
   items: [{
       xtype: "toolbar",
       docked: "top",
       height: 45,
       title: "First App"
   },{
       xtype:'billingform'
   }]
   ```

Correct these and then see if it helps.